# Call to a member function format() on string

Tags: datetime, symfony

I'm trying to save a datetime value using an input but I keep getting the error

> Call to a member function format() on string

This is how I've been trying to save the value.

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="end_date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $endDate;


/**
 * Set endDate
 *
 * @param \DateTime $endDate
 *
 * @return voorstellingen
 */
public function setEndDate($endDate)
{
    $time = new \DateTime($this->endDate = $endDate);
    $time->format('Y-m-d');
    return $time;
}
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Can anyone help me?

edit: changing my setter to

```
/**
     * Set endDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $endDate
     *
     * @return voorstellingen
     */
    public function setEndDate($endDate)
    {
        $this->endDate = new \DateTime($endDate);
        return $this;
    }
```

solved the issue.

Comment: Your setter is confused. As a doctrine entity, `setEndDate()` should be returning `$this`, and you should be relying on the ORM to turn the DateTime to and from what's stored in the database.

Comment: Yes, that's it! thanks! I changed my setter to return $this and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Like [jbafford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5760706/jbafford) said setters in Symfony Should `return $this`.